# iOS SwipeAction sometimes moves behind UITableViewCell and it doesn't move when swiping left or right

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios13

I implement in controller, my device testing is iPhone6S iOS 13.3.1, Xcode version is 11.3.1, my project is in Swift 5. when I swipe to left or right sometimes the swipeview move behind cell and cell not move, the custom tableview cell is normal...a view in center with constraint to superview to simulated spaced in cells and willBeginEditingRowAt i change size and y position of nativeview of swipe to have equal height size with simulated spacing cell.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.configtable()
    }

    private func configtable(){
        let tbl = UITableView.init()
        self.view.addSubview(tbl)

        tbl.register(UINib.init(nibName: "TempcellTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TempcellTableViewCell")
        tbl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tbl.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        tbl.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        tbl.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: self.view.topAnchor, multiplier: 10).isActive = true
        tbl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        tbl.delegate = self
        tbl.dataSource = self
        tbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        self.filltable()
        tbl.reloadData()
    }


    func filltable(){
        self.arraypersonas = [persona]()
        self.arraypersonas.append(persona.init(ci: 1, nombre: "Person 1"))
        self.arraypersonas.append(persona.init(ci: 2, nombre: "Person 2"))
        self.arraypersonas.append(persona.init(ci: 3, nombre: "Person 3"))
        self.arraypersonas.append(persona.init(ci: 4, nombre: "Person 4"))
        self.arraypersonas.append(persona.init(ci: 5, nombre: "Person 5"))
        self.arraypersonas.append(persona.init(ci: 6, nombre: "Person 6"))
        self.arraypersonas.append(persona.init(ci: 7, nombre: "Person 7"))

    }
```

and tableview delegate functions are:

```
 extension TCViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(#function)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.arraypersonas.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 110
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willBeginEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TempcellTableViewCell{
            if let spvcell = cell.superview{
                for svswipe in spvcell.subviews{

                    let typeview = type(of: svswipe.self)
                    if typeview.description() == "UISwipeActionPullView"{
                        svswipe.frame.size.height = 100
                        svswipe.frame.origin.y = 5

                    }

                }
            }

        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TempcellTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TempcellTableViewCell
        let item = self.arraypersonas[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbltitle.text = "\(item.ci) - \(item.nombre)"
        cell.containerbg.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let Cancel = UIContextualAction.init(style: .normal, title: "Cancel") { (action, view, nil) in
             print("Cancel")

         }
         Cancel.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

         let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration.init(actions: [Cancel])
         config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false // Prevent swiping



         return config
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
        let Checkin = UIContextualAction.init(style: .normal, title: "Check-in") { (action, view, nil) in
            print("Checkin")

        }
        Checkin.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        //Checkin.image = UIImage.init(named: Constants.images.iconcheckinhouse)

        let Noshow = UIContextualAction.init(style: .normal, title: "No Show") { (action, view, nil) in
            print("No show")

        }
        Noshow.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
        //Noshow.image = UIImage.init(named: Constants.images.iconthumbsdown)

        //arrayactions.append(Cancel)
        let config = UISwipeActionsConfiguration.init(actions: [Noshow,Checkin])
        config.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false // Prevent swiping

        return config
    }
```

In mi Custom TableViewCell have:

```
class TempcellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var containerbg: UIView!

    @IBOutlet var lbltitle: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }   
}
```

[image: Layout Image tableviewcell]
[image: Propertys]
[image: Propertys2]

Images Xcode propertys Constraint of subviews TableviewCell
[image: Constraints Contentview]
[image: Constraints view inside ContentView]
[image: Constraints Label inside view]

Images of bug:

[image: Bug scene]

Comment: The problem could also lie in the UITableViewCell itself, perhaps related to it's layout so perhaps showing the code for that would help.

Comment: Sure, thanks for answer, also now add code/layout images and property cell of Xcode.

Comment: That doesn't show the constraints you have setup for the cell.

Comment: ok, Now add screenshot of property xcode of subview tableviewcell to show constraints

Comment: sorry I don't understand what you mean by "sometimes the swipeview move behind cell and cell not move" . maybe record the phone screen as a video using quicktime and then turn it into a gif or something and add to your question. it will be useful to see the actual behaviour otherwise everyone will picture something else in their head.

Comment: ok, now add gif of bug scene